# Contact form 7 giving 404 error without Login - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

ran into a problem with contact form 7 where I can no longer submit any emails unless I am logged into WordPress. Would love any thoughts on how to resolve this if someone has found a solution.

**I attempted the following with no luck**
1) reverted plugin to a pervious version
2) disabled rest wp-api

Any pointers and or ideas would be appreciated.

**Error:**

```
{
 “code”: “rest_cannot_access”,
 “message”: “Only authenticated users can access the REST API.”,
 “data”: {
  “status”: 401
 }
}
```

Comment: disabled the plugins one by one and change the theme to default one is it working in this way?

Comment: Read the message parameter there is a issue. Your rest api is access able for the login user only. you need to change that and your problem will be  automatically vanish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After disabling each plugin as suggested by @dipmala I found the culprit. Password protect plugin seems to be causing this issue. I disabled that plugin, cleared cache, etc.. and logged out and form worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Three years later, I had same issue, with same cause. Problem solved.

Comment: This needs more Google love (y) Didn't come up first, but eventually did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Password protect plugin seems to be causing this issue. I disabled that plugin.